# similar to fibonacci, how to prove that

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, probability-theory

How to show that ratio of consecutive lucas number converges to golden ratio such that$\dfrac{L_n}{L_{n-1}}= \phi$

Comment: What is the recurrence relation and initial conditions for Lucas numbers

Comment: $L_0 = 2$ and $L_1=1$

Comment: Presumably you know, or have been exposed to, a proof for the Fibonaccis – what happens when you try to adjust that proof to work for Lucas?

Comment: bit confusing sir / maam

Comment: Sorry, saying "bit confusing" doesn't give me much to go on. What exactly is confusing? What do you neeed? Also, you've had four answers. Have you found any of them helpful?

Comment: yes sir im okay thanks

Comment: If you found one of the answers helpful, you could indicate that by "accepting" it, by clicking in the check mark next to that answer.

Comment: all sir thanks bdw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence relation for Lucas's numbers is $L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}=L_{n}$ for $n\ge 2$. The roots of the characteristic polynomial $t^2=t+1$ are $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Hence $$L_n=c_1\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+c_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$ where you can determine $c_1,c_2$ from initial conditions. Now find the ratio.

Comment: How do we know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{L_{n+1}}{L_n} = \frac{c_1}{c_2}$? I understand that they're the initial conditions, but I don't see why their ratio has to be the limit.

Comment: No no their rao is not the limit. But tui find the limit you need to find the constants first. You can find the limit, by letting $n$ go to $\infty$ on both sides of the recurrence relation.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this? The manipulation you describe seems non-trivial to me.

Comment: $L_n/L_{n-1}=1+L_{n-2}/L_{n-1}$, so If the required limit is $x$, then taking limit on both sides we get $x=1+1/x$

Comment: I think what I did was a little bit unnecessarily cumbersome. The others have given precisely what you needed. I would delete the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Lucas numbers are defined by the recurrence relation $L_{n+2} = L_{n+1} + L_n$ subject to initial conditions $L_0 = 2$ and $L_1 = 1$.

For any $n \ge 0$, introduce an auxiliary sequence $p_n$ by:

$$p_n = \frac{L_{n+1}-\phi L_n}{\phi L_{n+1} + L_n}
\quad\iff\quad
\frac{L_{n+1}}{L_n} = \frac{p_n + \phi}{-\phi p_n + 1}
$$
This auxiliary sequence $p_n$ satisfies a very simple recurrence relation.

$$\begin{align}p_{n+1} 
&= \frac{(L_{n+1} + L_n) - \phi L_{n+1}}{\phi(L_{n+1}+L_n) + L_{n+1}}
= \frac{(1-\phi)L_{n+1} + L_n}{(1+\phi)L_{n+1} + \phi L_n}
= -\frac{1}{\phi}\frac{(\phi^2-\phi)L_{n+1} - \phi L_n}{\phi^2 L_{n+1} + \phi L_n}\\
&= -\frac{1}{\phi^2}\frac{L_{n+1} - \phi L_n}{\phi L_{n+1} + L_n}
= -\frac{1}{\phi^2} p_n
\end{align}
$$
Solving this recurrence relation, we find $$p_n = \left(-\frac{1}{\phi^2}\right)^{n} p_0 = \left(-\frac{1}{\phi^2}\right)^{n}\frac{1-2\phi}{\phi+2} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\phi^{2n+1}}$$

Since $\frac{1}{\phi^2}  < 1$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} p_n = 0$. As a result,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{L_{n+1}}{L_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_n + \phi}{-\phi p_n + 1} = \frac{0 + \phi}{-\phi(0) + 1} = \phi$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{L_{n+1}}{L_n} = X$$ but we also have
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{L_{n+1}}{L_n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{L_{n} + L_{n-1}}{L_n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\big(1 +\frac{L_{n-1}}{L_n}\big) = 1 + \frac 1X$$

Hence $$X = 1 + \frac 1X$$ or equivalently $$X^2 = X + 1$$ or $$X^2 - X - 1 = 0$$

And so, after solving the quadratic equation, we get $$X = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{L_{n+1}}{L_n} = \frac{1+\sqrt5}2 = \phi$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the limit and recall that addition and multiplication is continuous. Then

Note that $\phi=\phi+1/\phi$ since it is a zero of $x^2-x-1$.

Note that $L:=\lim_{n \to \infty}L_n/L_{n-1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}L_{n+1}/L_{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} 1+L_{n-1}/L_n =1+1/L$